# ListRows.Add does not make data in adjacent columns move down

Tags: excel, vba

I've recently written the following code, to add a new row to my Excel tables.

```
Sub AddRow()

    Dim loTable As ListObject
    Dim lrRow As ListRow
    Set loTable = Selection.ListObject
    
    Set lrRow = loTable.ListRows.Add

End Sub
```

My problem is I want all cells to move down a row, but my code only work for the columns which contains the table.

I have preferred the ListRows.Add over the Insert-method, as it contains the autofilled data of the tables, which I couldn't get to work with the Insert row method.

I've tried some workarounds I found on StackOverflow, but they don't seem to help and I can't figure it out :(

Is there anyone, who knows the fix to this?

Best regards :)

Comment: The table (`ListObject`) is independent of the other columns on the sheet. So you would need to use `Rows.Insert` and then autofill the data, or `ListRows.Add` and then shift the other cells separately.

Comment: That is what i feared :( Sadly, i'll need to figure out a fix. Maybe i can add a row under before and set the "AlwaysInsert" to false. 

Also BigBen, i can't seem to upvote your answer although it helped me. But big thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table (`ListObject`) is independent of the other columns on the sheet.

Your options include:

- Using `Rows.Insert` to insert an entire row, and then autofilling the data within the table.
- Using `ListRows.Add` to add a row to the table, and then shifting the other cells separately.